# Change background colour of div inside canvas Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this program where I'm creating a paint software. When i press the ctrl key while moving the mouse, it turns on the eraser. I've got a div element that's a box that's tracking the mouse so the user knows where the mouse is in the canvas.

The problem I'm having is that I can't change the colour of the div element to white when it goes to eraser mode. Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
    <title>Coursework 1 Template v1.0</title>

    <style>
            #box {
          pointer-events: none;
          background-color: #000000;
          width: 5px;
          height: 5px;
        }
        </style>

    <script>
        var oCanvas, oCanvasContext; //declare the global variables used to hold and control the canvas element
        var sFillColour; //create a global variable used to hold the active/selected colour
        var sCanvasColour; //create a global variable used to hold the canvas colour
        var iMouseX, iMouseY; //declare the global variables used to hold the mouse's coordinates
        var iBrushWidth, iBrushHeight; //declare the global variables used to hold the selected brush sizes
            function fnTrackMouse(e) {
            //this function is called "everytime" the user's mouse is moved when over the associated element (in this case the canvas)
            //we have also added the ability for it to accept a parameter (called e, actually we can call it anything but as event is a reserved work "e" makes some sense
            var canvasRect = oCanvas.getBoundingClientRect(); //use this function to dynamically get the size of the canvas and its position
            iMouseX=(e.clientX - canvasRect.left - 3); //modify the original position of the mouse by accounting for the position on the canvas; on the x
            iMouseY=(e.clientY - canvasRect.top - 3); //modify the original position of the mouse by accounting for the position on the canvas; on the y

            var bx = document.getElementById("box");
            bx.style.left = (iMouseX + 1)+"px";
            bx.style.top = (iMouseY + 1)+"px";
            fnDebugMessage("Working!"+iMouseX)

            if (e.ctrlKey) { //this checks if the user has pressed the control key to use the eraser funtion
                fnSetFillColour(sCanvasColour); //calls the fnSetFillColour function with the background colour of the canvas in the parameter
                bx.style.background-color = #ffffff
            }       


            if (e.buttons==1) { //this checks to see if the user is pressing the left mouse button (1 = the left mouse button)
                //the user has pressed the left button - so lets start painting
                fnPaint(iMouseX, iMouseY, iBrushWidth, iBrushHeight); //call the fnPaint function and pass it the coordinates and size to paint
            }

        </script>

</head>

<!-- 
    this "onload" event fires when the HTML <body> has loaded. In essence, we are telling the browser that once the page 
    has completely loaded all the content to execute a script. 
    in this case the function being called is "fnInitialise" and we are passing it two parameters: 
        the first (work out how this sets the width) = 100 
        the second (work out how this sets the height) = 100 
-->


<body onload="fnInitialise(100, 100);">

    <!-- 
        this div block (HTML page divider) is used to hold the entire interactive painting HTML elements 
        the benefit of putting multiple elements in a single container is that if you set the location of the 
        container each of the elements held by the container will move relative to it; move one, move all 
    -->
    <div id="cw1MainContainer">


        <!-- this div block is only used to hold the HTML canvas element -->
        <div id="cw1CanvasContainer">
            <canvas id="cw1Canvas" onmousemove="fnTrackMouse(event);" onkeypress="fnBrushSize(event);"></canvas>
            <div id="box" style="position:absolute;" />
            <!-- 
                by specifing the onmouseover event the canvas will call the "fnTrackMouse" function EVERY time the 
                mouse moves 1 pixel over the canvas.
                by passing the JavaScript "event" we are effectively also passing details about the event, 
                e.g. where the mouse was, what buttons were pressed etc. 
            -->
        </div>
        </div>      

</body>
```

It's throwing a Invalid left-hand side in assignment error. How do I change the background colour of the div element?
Please let me know if you want to see the rest of my code

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change it from this

```
bx.style.background-color = #ffffff
```

to this

```
box.style.backgroundColor = "#333333";
```

so no need to use (-) in the word backgroundColor..

I wish it helps

Comment: Thanks that worked! Well, it didn't work in the beginning, but I changed "#333333" to "#ffffff" and that worked perfectly. Cheers